# Initial State of Redux Store with JSON Data?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I am working on React app where the state is managed by redux. I am using actions.js file to fetch JSON data and store it directly in the store. The initial Store has just one key (data) in its obj with null as its value.

I use componentDidMount() Lifecycle to call the function which updates the store's data key with the JSON data I receive. However, whenever I load my app it gives an error because it finds the data value as null.

I get it. componentDidMount() executes after the app is loaded and the error doesn't let it execute. I tried using componentWillMount() but it also gives the same error. ( Which I use in JSX )

When I try to chanage the data's value from null to an empty obj it works for some level but after I use it's nested objects and arrays. I get error.

I wanna know what is the way around it. What should I set the vaue of inital State or should you use anyother lifecycle.

Comment: you might want to share some code

Comment: The code is quite large to post here

Comment: I dont know how complex your state would be or how many reducers you have, but I always recomend to preserve your initial state in a constant, at least the structure, datatypes, lately you can load your fetched state and dispatch it

Comment: @Joe'swiZaT I agree with you creating the initial state with complete structure is quite challenging because JSON data is nested over 20 times. This is a lot of work with potential mistakes to happen.

Answer (score 1):

If your primary `App` component can't function properly unless the state has been loaded then I suggest moving the initialization logic up a level such that you only render your current component *after* the redux state has already been populated.

---

class version

```
class LoaderComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if ( ! this.props.isLoaded ) {
      this.props.loadState();
    }
  }
  render() {
    if ( this.props.isLoaded ) {
      return <YourCurrentComponent />;
    } else {
      return <Loading/>
    }
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    isLoaded: state.data === null,
  }),
  {loadState}
)(LoaderComponent);
```

---

Try something like this.  The `mapStateToProps` subscribes to the store to see when the state is loaded and provides that info as an `isLoaded` prop.  The `loadState` in `mapDispatchToProps` is whatever action creator your current `componentDidMount` is calling.

---

hooks version

```
export const LoaderComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const isLoaded = useSelector(state => state.data === null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoaded) {
      dispatch(loadState());
    }
  }, [dispatch, isLoaded]);

  if (isLoaded) {
    return <YourCurrentComponent />;
  } else {
    return <Loading />
  }
}
```

---

And of course you would remove the fetching actions from the `componentDidMount` of the current component.